# Setting dates to tabs dynamically

Tags: java, android, date, android-fragments, tabs

I'm trying to get the current date to my tabs but the date to the left is not decreasing by one. I'm setting todays date to OneFragment then increasing the date by 1 in TwoFragment. This part is working fine but when i try to get the previous date from today to appear in ThreeFragment it is not working as intended.

Current: ThreeFragment(May 1, 2016 | Apr 30, 2016) OneFragmet(May 2, 2016) TwoFragment(May 3, 2016 | May 4, 2016)

I want ThreeFragment tabs to show the dates like this: (Apr 30, 2016 | May 1, 2016)

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Date today = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String todate = dateFormat1.format(today.getTime());

    for(int j = 2; j >= 0; j--) {
        Date decr = addDays(today, -1);
        String yesterday = dateFormat1.format(decr.getTime());
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), yesterday);
    }

    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), todate);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        String tomo = dateFormat1.format(cal.getTime());
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), tomo);

    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public static Date addDays(Date d, int days)
{
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + days * 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L);
    return d;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ccsnoopy said, but the addDays method is having a side-effect on the today variable (which is why it almost worked before), so try this instead.

```
for(int j = 2; j > 0; j--) {
    Date decr = addDays(new Date(), -j);
    String yesterday = dateFormat1.format(decr.getTime());
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), yesterday);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first loop to this:

```
for(int j = 2; j > 0; j--) {
    Date decr = addDays(today, -j);
    String yesterday = dateFormat1.format(decr.getTime());
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), yesterday);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but thank you for the input.